# Print specific row in 10x10 array MIPS

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

```
table:  .word  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10
    .word 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
    .word 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30
    .word 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40
    .word 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50
    .word 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60
    .word 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70
    .word 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80
    .word 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90
    .word 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100
```

This is the array that is created

```
one: #Print a row
print_str("Enter a row number to print: ")
li $v0, 5
syscall

move $t0, $v0
sw $a2, number

mul $a2, $a2, 10
sub $a2, $a2 , -10

bge $t0, 10, main

lw $t2, 0($t1)
    addi $t1, $t1, 4


li $v0, 1      
move $a0, $t2
    syscall

    li $a0, 32
    li $v0, 11  
    syscall

    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    j one
```

Trying to print a specific row in mips. ive got this but it doesnt seem to print anything out.

i have tried other things with no success

Comment: What do you think `$a2` and `$t1` contain? Since you have not set them to anything. Comment your code and use your debugger/simulator to single step the program to see what it's doing. You don't even have a loop to print a row.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Ill give a few more things a shot